# Changing the identifier of a UIBarButton Item to an image in swift

Tags: ios, image, swift, uibarbuttonitem

In an iOS app I am making, I have set the identifier of a bar button item programmatically using:

```
homeTitleBar.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Trash, target: self, action: nil)
```

Which changes the button to a trash can.

My question is, after that, how can I then change it to a custom image.

```
homeTitleBar.leftBarButtonItem?.image = UIImage(named: "settingsIcon")
```

does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
homeTitleBar.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named: "settingsIcon"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
```